# Why my python do not work with seaborn

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn, statsmodels

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sklearn
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import seaborn as sns


sns.set(); np.random.seed(0)
x = np.random.randn(100)

sns.distplot(x)
```

I just copy the example from the documention,but I get such error,I have try to change the enviroment such in shell to run it .But fail too.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/Betterwittyman/Desktop/job_25/别人的/pdf_model2.py", line 13, in <module>
sns.distplot(x)

TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

Answer (score 4):

Can you tell me the numpy and statsmodel version that you use ?

**You can try the following:**

**1)** Update the statsmodel package using

```
pip install -U statsmodels
```

**2)** can you try to run the following and let me if it works?

```
sns.distplot(x, bins=50, kde=False)
plt.show()
```

**P.S:** your code works for me using: numpy: 1.11.3, scipy: 0.18.1, statsmodels: 0.6.1

Comment: Wow it works ,but why the Kde =False will affect the result?all the package needed is same to you.Thanks!

Comment: @TomJhonson-FFT not sure why it did not work but I read that a lot of people have the same problem. If you solved your problem you can mark the answer as accepted

Comment: I did really thanks for you answer ,but my reputation is less than 15,thus i can't mark it .

Comment: @TomJhonson-FFT maybe a moderator will do it. Glad I could help with your problem

Comment: @TomJhonson-FFT you can mark now the answer as accepted This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution

Answer (score 0):

May be the version is not up to date.so follow the below command it worked.

`sudo pip install --upgrade seaborn`

Answer (score -2):

This may solve your error:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sklearn
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import seaborn as sns


sns.set()
np.random.seed(0)
x = np.random.randn(100)

sns.distplot(x)
```

Comment: Does it work on your computer? I just copy it ,but it doesn't work